# How to configure classpath for maven exec:java?

Tags: java, maven, jar, classpath, pom.xml

How to add some local **folders** to the classpath when executing using maven exec:java? Each folder contains multiple jars, so I prefer not to add each jar separately.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Apache Maven Install Plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/index.html

You can use the install-file goal (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) to install your external jars to your local maven repository and then include them as normal maven dependencies.

Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/

Answer (score 1):

I thought you could use

```
 addjars-maven-plugin
```

to configure each of your directories and set the goal as
`add-jars`